# How to shutdown the computer from Openbox as a menu item?

Tags: shutdown, openbox

How can I add a menu item to Openbox which launches a prompt to cancel or provide a root password, then shuts down X and the computer if the correct password was given? The question [Shutting the computer down from Openbox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73187/shutting-the-computer-down-from-openbox) is related, but the answer involved typing, not clicking through them menus.

The [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openbox#Menus) suggests that one add a `systemctl poweroff` menu like this, but the menus do not appear to work:

```
<item label="Shutdown">
    <action name="Execute">
        <command>systemctl poweroff</command>
    </action>
</item>
```

I am using Debian 7.0.

Comment: why not something like this https://kmandla.wordpress.com/2007/10/27/howto-shut-down-linux-from-the-openbox-right-click-menu/ and add your user to sudoers to allow shutdown

Answer (score 2):

On my desktop I use the following menu items for rebooting and halting:

```
<item label='Shutdown'>
   <action name='Execute'>
     <command>/usr/local/bin/opBox-exit.sh halt</command>
   </action>
</item>
<item label='Reboot'>
   <action name='Execute'>
     <command>/usr/local/bin/opBox-exit.sh reboot</command>
   </action>
</item>
```

The script `/usr/local/bin/opBox-exit.sh` uses `zenity` to open a cancel-confirm-dialog and when the confirm button was pressed it executes `sudo halt` or `sudo reboot`. I configured the `sudoers` file so my user wouldn't have to type in a password to run `halt` and `reboot` with `sudo`. For me this is more convenient. Here is the full script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -z $1 ];then
   echo "Usage: $0 [reboot|halt]"
   exit
fi
if [ $1 = reboot ];then
   zenity --question --ok-label "Reboot" --text "Reboot $HOST?" && sudo /sbin/reboot
elif [ $1 = halt ];then
   zenity --question --ok-label "Shudown" --text "Shutdown $HOST?" && sudo /sbin/halt -p
fi
```

When you want a dialog for the users password I would recommend that you use `gksudo halt -p` instead of the whole `zenity --question ... && sudo halt -p` stuff. For this your user would still need to be able to execute commands via `sudo`. Take a look at `man sudoers` for more information.

`gksudo` is in the Debain package `gksu`.